# Can't make Firefox autostart at boot Lubuntu 22.04

Tags: autostart

I added firefox in the LXQt autostart settings, but after log out / in firefox doesn't start...
Please answer with GUI solutions
TIA
Klaus

Comment: Can you add more details of how you added Firefox to autostart?

Comment: You've not said what you've done, I suspect it's as documented here (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html?highlight=autostart) but its helpful if you're specific & tell us exactly what you did, what you told to *autostart* etc.  FYI:  I suspect `firefox` is harder due to being a *snap* package; it requires *snapd* infrastructure running first, but that's assuming default `firefox` & you gave few specifics.

Comment: It's a fresh install of Matt Gadient iso https://stuff.mattgadient.com/linux-mac-iso/lubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64-mac-mattgadient.com.iso In LXQt settings /  autostart I added firefox, following logout / login

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Lubuntu seems to be covered...

Comment: Matt Gadient's isos just use a 32bit EFI boot

Comment: You've not using Lubuntu... as they come either from https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ or https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours  (*which will both download from cdimage.ubuntu.com in the end too*).  You're asking about a Ubuntu based product, which is **not** a Ubuntu product.  If you want help with Matt Gadient's ISOs, go ask Matt Gadient as they are not Ubuntu/Lubuntu products.